# Me aparece este error al ejecutar: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 at Extra.main(Extra.java:9)

Tags: java

¿Cómo hago para que el programa genere números aleatorios de los primeros 10 números naturales?, pero, que solo almacenen los **0 y 1.**

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class 1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rd = new Random();
        int[][] matriz = new int[10][5];

        for (int a = 0; a < matriz.length; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < matriz.length; b++) {
                matriz[a][b] = rd.nextInt(10);
            }
        }
        String respuesta = "";
        for (int a = 0; a < matriz.length; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < matriz.length; b++) {
                respuesta = respuesta + "" + matriz[a][b];
            }
            respuesta = respuesta + "," + "\n";
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hay 2 cosas que estan mal. El primero es que no escribas con mayusculas porque parece que "gritas". Lo segundo ¿Que tiene que ver el titulo con la descripcion? Te recomiendo leer [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: ¿Cómo que sólo los 0 y 1? ¿Para qué entonces obtener aleatorios de los naturales?

Answer (score 0):

Nose a qué te refieres con que "Almacene los 0 y 1" pero para  genera un número random del 0 al 10 se podría hacer de la siguiente manera

int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 11);

Comment: a almacenar me refiero a que en mi matriz quede rellena con 0 y1 :c

Answer (score 0):

La manera mas sencilla es guardar el random en una variable y validar su valor, ahora, depende que quieras:

1. Guardar el valor en la matriz hasta que sea 0 o 1.
2. Solo se almacene el valor en la matriz si este es 0 o 1, sin embargo, por defecto, desde que se creo la matriz de tipo int, la matriz ya se encuentra llena de 0.

Para el primer caso seria algo como:

```
for(int a=0; a<matriz.length;a++){          
    for(int b=0; b<matriz.length;b++){
        int valorMatriz;
        do{
             valorMatriz = rd.nextInt(11);
          }while(valorMatriz>1);
        matriz[a][b]=valorMatriz;
    }
}
```

Para el segundo caso:

```
 for(int a=0; a<matriz.length;a++){          
        for(int b=0; b<matriz.length;b++){
            int valorMatriz = rd.nextInt(11);
            if(valorMatriz<=1){
                matriz[a][b]=valorMatriz;
            }
        }
    }
```